# Historic (start of 2017 season) Formula 1 betting odds

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, historical, sports

I'm looking for historic (i.e. from the start of 2017 season onwards) betting odds for Formula 1 races. Specifically, I'm looking for data such as winning odds for each driver (and/or team) for each race, podium odds and generally as more data as possible.

I've built a machine-learning F1 race prediction engine and I want to check if my predictions could somehow guide any betting endeavours.